# How can I process images in loop codeigniter?

Tags: image, codeigniter, image-processing, resize

I have two resize functions that I would like to perform one after the other using codeigniters image manipulation class:http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

At the moment when I try running the function only the first one works, it ignores the second.

I have added `$this->image_lib->clear()` which according to codeigniters user guide: 'resets all of the values used when processing an image. You will want to call this if you are processing images in a loop.'

Why can't I run the two seperate resize functions? How would I go about doing this??

```
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $upload_path . '/thumbs/',
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $this->image_lib->clear();

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 620,
            'height' => 410
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use clear then store configs in two different arrays.
**$this->image_lib->clear();** is used to flush previous settings & to add new.